# problem related to wronskian of non trivial solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the equation $x''+a_1(t)x'+a_2(t)x=0$, where $a_1,a_2$ are continuous on some interval $I$ containing $t_0$. Suppose $x_1$ is a solution such that $x_1(t)\neq0$  $ \forall t\in I$. Then,
>
> - (a) there is a second solution $x_2$ on $I$ such that $W(x_1,x_2)(t_0)=1$
> - (b) there does not exist any $x_2$ such that $W(x_1,x_2)(t_0)=1$
> - (c) $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent
> - (d) there exists $x_2$ such that $W(x_1,x_2)(t_0)=0$

i know that if Wronskian $W(x_1,x_2)$ is zero at any point, then it is identically zero, but i have no idea in how to proceed in this problem.

thanks for your time in advance...

Comment: What is $x_2$ in (c)? You know what the Wronskian is? What its differential equation is?

Comment: @LutzL:$x_2$ is a solution of given differential equation and i do have idea regarding wronskian

Comment: Then study your scripts and textbooks (or wikipedia, which is quite complete if of varying quality on mathematical topics of medium difficulty), because without that knowledge you will fail this topic, even if you get the answer for this task from somewhere.